# Finite element mesh software

Tags: finite-element, fortran, adaptive-mesh-refinement

I'm looking for a program to obtain meshes to finite element codes 2D and 3D as complete as possible, preferably in fortran 90 or C/C++.
For example, softwares "Triangle" or  "TetGen" generate meshes but I would like a software that creates meshes with more information (for example, normal vectors).

May you suggest to me some software?

Comment: Take a look at Gmsh (http://geuz.org/gmsh/).

Comment: Also you can look at salome http://www.salome-platform.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say [Gmsh](http://geuz.org/gmsh/). I used it for a few finite element projects, and it was mostly easy to work with. The mesh output formats are very parseable, and there's at least one third-party parser ([MeshPy](https://github.com/inducer/meshpy)) that can parse the output. It also has a C++ API, and the mailing list gets enough traffic (probably 10-20 messages a week) that your questions might be answered (in my experience, it's something like a 1-in-2 chance).